# Can't change link for navigation item

Tags: menus

I'm customzing a wordpress theme so problem is that i've to change a link. its in arabic for example  instead of this `<a href='somelink.com'>`  i want to  make it like this   but problem is that  i dont find link for the item see attached image please [image]

now how do i change  its link?

Answer (score 0):

From the Screenshot it seems like this navigation item actually links to a page/post (or custom post type)? So you need to edit the page/post itself, by switching into the editor from this specific post/page and click on "Change Permalink".